# Dynamic Spinners - if an item is selected from one spinner, hide it from other spinners - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-spinner

How to hide an item from other spinners that is currently selected in one spinner?

I've tried removing the items via ArrayList of strings and ArrayAdapters, but I've noticed as soon as it's removed from the list, the selection is no longer referenced to the list item (because it does not exist anymore).

Now suppose, I have 4 spinner that are created dynamically and they all have the same ArrayList as their resource and now i would like to use this adapter to fetch the position of the selected item from 1 spinner and then hide it from 3 other spinners.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStops; i++) {
                AddStopView stopView = new AddStopView(getActivity());
                stopView.setCallback(BaseBookingFragment.this);
                stopView.setPassengerNames(extraPassengerNames);
                stopViews.add(stopView);
                parent.addView(stopView, viewPosition);
            }
```

In above code i am creating Stop Views dynamically and each Stop View having Passenger Name spinner. And these all spinners have the same ArrayList as their resource.

piece of code from AddStopView.java

```
public AddStopView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}

public void setCallback(StopViewCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

public void setPassengerNames(List<String> passengerNames) {
    this.passengerNames = passengerNames;
    passengerAdapter.setNames(passengerNames);
}

private void initialize() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_stop, this);

    passengerAdapter = new ExtraPassengerAdapter(getContext());
    passengerAdapter.setNames(passengerNames);
    nameSpinner.setAdapter(passengerAdapter);
    nameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (view == null) {
                return;
            }
            passengerName = (String) view.getTag();

            if (position != 0)
                callback.updatePassengerList(AddStopView.this, (position - 1));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

code of call back of nameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener

```
@Override
public void updatePassengerList(AddStopView addStopView, int position) {

    for (String passName : extraPassengerNames) {
        if (addStopView.getPassengerName().equals(passName)) {
            extraPassengerNames.remove(passName);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (AddStopView stopView : stopViews) {
        if (!stopView.equals(addStopView))
            stopView.setPassengerNames(extraPassengerNames);
    }
}
```

code from ExtraPassengerAdapter.java

```
public class ExtraPassengerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public ExtraPassengerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    names.add(get0Position());
}


public void setNames(List<String> names) {
    this.names.clear();
    this.names.add(get0Position());
    this.names.addAll(names);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return names.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_stop, parent, false);
    String name = getItem(position);
    textView.setText(name);
    textView.setTag(name);
    return textView;
}

private String get0Position() {
    return context.getString(R.string.passenger_name);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to solve you problem is to create one list with all possible options and 4 lists with 4 adapters for each spinner. When something selected you update each list according to logic you described and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` for each adapter.

Comment: I did the same way. Spinners are creating dynamically and according to created spinners, ArrayList of PassengerName and ExtraPassengerAdapter are also creating for each of spinner. but no luck.

Comment: you forgot to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` for each adapter

Comment: Ok. Thanks Max. Let me check.

Comment: No. I have tried almost tricky code to find solution and finally i dropped that idea as i had no much time for that and kept my code as it is.